# Place symbol in Status Bar with Cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, statusbar

i just googled for that, but found nothing.

Is there a possibility to use cordova for displaying a symbol or a value in the statusbar from iPhones? I'm using a VPN Client from SonicWall which displays a VPN Symbol in Statusbar when the App is running.

So i just had an idea, but i don't know how to achieve that. The StatusBar Plugin is just for style, not for displaying a value which increases or decreases every 30 seconds.

So: Is there a possiblity to do so like i described?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: thx for that question. exactly mine